# select columns based on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to translate SQL statement to Pandas:

```
select PolicyNumber, 
       Coverage 
  from  ClaimsData 
  where AccidentState = 'AZ' and Coverage = 'Liability'
```

I know how select columns for single condition (AccidentState = 'AZ') but how can I add another condition?

```
ClaimsData[["PolicyNumber","Coverage","AccidentState"]] [ClaimsData["AccidentState"]=="AZ"]  # and here I need to add another condition
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can chain conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` and filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) rows by conditions ([`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)) and columns by columns names in `list`:

```
mask = (ClaimsData["AccidentState"]=="AZ") & (ClaimsData["Coverage"]=="Liability")
df = ClaimsData.loc[mask, ["PolicyNumber","Coverage"]]
```

Like @Sandeep Kadapa pointed in comments there is alternative with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
q = "AccidentState == 'AZ' & Coverage == 'Liability'"
df = ClaimsData.query(q)[["PolicyNumber","Coverage"]]
```

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way first choose the columns I need and then specify conditions? I came from SQL background and that would be so much easier

Comment: @Oleg Check [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), this would help.

Comment: @Oleg - It is in one step - filtering by rows, and filtering by columns.